# Porting Unix to Windows- usage of pwd.h

Tags: c, windows, unix, mingw, posix-api

I'm trying to compile [libUnihan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libunihan/) code with MinGW, but have run into a function which requires porting. The purpose of the function is to get a canonical path representation.  It uses `pwd.h` (which is POSIX, and MinGW isn't) so it can account for the use of '~' to mean the home directory by retrieving a `passwd` struct, which contains `pw_dir`. I did find a little information [here](http://www.suacommunity.com/dictionary/getpwnam-entry.php), and a port of `realpath` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/), but I am still entirely at a loss as to how to deal with this. With MinGW, I still have a home directory represented by `~` and located at `/home/nate`, but since it isn't POSIX, I don't have `pwd.h` to help me find where this home directory is.

**Q:** How can I port the function below to work properly with MinGW?

```
/**
 * Return the canonicalized absolute pathname.
 *
 * It works exactly the same with realpath(3), except this function can handle the path with ~,
 * where realpath cannot.
 *
 * @param path The path to be resolved.
 * @param resolved_path Buffer for holding the resolved_path.
 * @return resolved path, NULL is the resolution is not sucessful.
 */
gchar*
truepath(const gchar *path, gchar *resolved_path){
    gchar workingPath[PATH_MAX];
    gchar fullPath[PATH_MAX];
    gchar *result=NULL;
    g_strlcpy(workingPath,path,PATH_MAX);

//     printf("*** path=%s \n",path);

    if ( workingPath[0] != '~' ){
        result = realpath(workingPath, resolved_path);
    }else{
        gchar *firstSlash, *suffix, *homeDirStr;
        struct passwd *pw;

        // initialize variables
        firstSlash = suffix = homeDirStr = NULL;

    firstSlash = strchr(workingPath, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        if (firstSlash == NULL)
            suffix = "";
        else
        {
            *firstSlash = 0;    // so userName is null terminated
            suffix = firstSlash + 1;
        }

        if (workingPath[1] == '\0')
            pw = getpwuid( getuid() );
        else
            pw = getpwnam( &workingPath[1] );

        if (pw != NULL)
            homeDirStr = pw->pw_dir;

        if (homeDirStr != NULL){
        gint ret=g_sprintf(fullPath, "%s%c%s", homeDirStr, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, suffix);
        if (ret>0){
        result = realpath(fullPath, resolved_path);
        }

    }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note that `~` on its own means the value of the `$HOME` environment variable, which is usually, but not necessarily, the same as `~user` for the current user.  The latter is the information from the password file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose is to implement `~[username]/` remapping logic. This sort of code makes sense in Linux/UNIX environments, but the most common use is just to refer to the user's own home directory.

For expediency, I'd just add support for the common case - `~/` - i.e. the current user, and not bother supporting the more general case - have it fail with an obvious error in that case.

The function to get the current user's home directory is [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx).

```
#include <windows.h>

char homeDirStr[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, 0, homeDirStr))) {
    // Do something with the path
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

In the case of a failed lookup of the user, the code you pasted does not try to replace that string, but simply returns `NULL`, so you could emulate that.

Comment: Throwing some compile errors; what do I pass in instead of CSIDL_PERSONAL?

Comment: That should also be `#include <Shlobj.h>` for that variable IIRC. The path returned is a windows path, and I think needs conversion (not on a Windows system to check if it works)

Comment: unless I'm missing something, `realpath` isn't in mingw either.

Comment: ignore my comment about the path needing conversion - mingw uses windows paths internally so that will work without additional changes