# Is there a pwd.h port for Visual Studio on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, posix

I am trying to look at some code I found browsing Github through the debugger, but (obviously) Visual Studio doesn't come native with POSIX headers. The header in question is `pwd.h`, which I cannot seem to find a Windows port for at all. Where could I find one that works?

Comment: Windows uses a substantially different scheme to identify and authenticate users or groups. Even though Microsoft's UCRT [implements  a large subset of the POSIX.1 C library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/compatibility), *pwd.h* isn't part of that.

Comment: You can't find `pwd.h` on Windows, but you can port it to Windows yourself. Refer to: [Porting Unix to Windows- usage of pwd.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371602/porting-unix-to-windows-usage-of-pwd-h)